# How to search array of objects by id when that id is within another array (JsonPath)?

Tags: jsonpath

I'm trying to use [JsonPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to filter an array of objects by id.  For each item in the array I want to filter it if its id is in a second array.

So for example I have the source array:

```
[
   {
     id: 1,
     name: "House"
   },

   {
     id: 2,
     name: "Hamer"
   },
   {
     id: 13,
     name: "Book"
   },
   {
     id: 45,
     name: "Truck"
   },
]
```

And I want to filter this array by id, if that id is in another array, for example:

```
[ 2, 13]
```

This should result in a filtered array of:

```
[
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Hamer"
    },
    {
      id: 13,
      name: "Book"
    }
]
```

I can figure out how to do this with a lengthy `or` statement with each item in the second array, but that seems like a pretty painful and silly way to filter one array by another.

How can I perform the above operation using JsonPath, but without an `or` for each array item in the second array?

Answer (score 1):

```
getItemsById = (arr, arr2) => {
     result = arr.filter(f => arr2.includes(f.id));
     console.log(result);
}
```